# Can class with initial param use Inversion of Control pattern (IoC)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I'm curious about that can the class with initial param using Inversion of Control pattern (IoC)?

Example :

A page with a search button can search order detail by Class helper instantiation.

class :

```cs
    public class OrderDetail
    {
        order order ;
        public OrderDetail(string orderID)
        {
            order = DumbOrderList().where(o=>o.orderID == OrderID);
        }
        public decimal GetPrice()
        {
            retrun order.Price;
        }
        public datetime GetDate()
        {
            retrun order.Date;
        }
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
```

Page:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Search(string orderID)
{
    OrderDetail orderHelper = new OrderDetail(orderID);

    return Json(orderHelper.GetPrice());
}
```

Page is depend on `OrderDetail` Class, and every search will instantiate class with `orderID`.

How to make `OrderDetail` Class using IoC pattern ?

Or if it can't using IoC pattern, so how can I make page not to depend on this class (Decoupling) ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the way you have designed your class could be improved. Instead of making your class dependent on some parameter to instantiate, make the methods of that class dependent.

I mean to say, redesign the OrderDetail class like below:

1.) Create an interface

```
public interface IOrderDetail 
{
    GetPrice(int orderId)
}
```

2.) Create a class that implements the interface

```
public class OrderDetail : IOrderDetail
{
    public GetPrice(int orderId) {....}
}
```

3.) Register dependency in IoC container

```
container.RegisterType<IOrderDetail, OrderDetail>();
```

4.) Use it like below in API Controller

```
public class SomeController : ApiController 
{

    private readonly IOrderDetail _orderDetail;

    public SomeController(IOrderDetail orderDetail) 
    {
        _orderDetail = orderDetail;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Search(string orderID)
    {
        return Json(_orderDetail.GetPrice(orderID));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With inversion of control pattern, you need to define an interface to which `Search` can delegate its behavior. Interface definition could be subjective, and therefore no single answer here.

If I were the person implementing inversion of control according to the example given in question, I'd do:

```
interface IOrderPriceGetter
{ 
    decimal GetByOrderId(int orderId);
}

class OrderPriceGetter : IOrderPriceGetter
{
    public decimal GetByOrderId(int orderId)
    {
        return new OrderDetail(orderId).GetPrice();
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Search(string orderID)
{
    // Injected via constructor
    IOrderPriceGetter getter = ...;

    return Json(getter.GetByOrderId(orderId));
}
```

Or I could also define interface as:

```
interface IOrderGetter
{ 
    OrderDetail GetOrder(int orderId);
}
```

Then use it like:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Search(string orderID)
{
    // Injected via constructor
    IOrderGetter getter = ...;

    return Json(getter.GetOrder(orderId).GetPrice());
}
```